# Should UIApplicationDelegate openURL's SourceApplication parameter ever be nil?

Tags: ios, objective-c

My iOS app receives files from other iOS apps via the UIApplicationDelegate's openURL method. I use the NSString *SourceApplication parameter in my app to keep track of the name of the app that sent the files to my app.

In iOS7 the SourceApplication parameter was always populated with strings like "getdropbox.dropbox", "google.Drive", or "evernote.iPhone.evernote".

After I (and several other users of my app) upgraded to iOS8, the SourceApplication parameter always seems to be nil. The url parameter is populated correctly with the URL to the file being sent to my app. It seems only the behavior of the SourceApplication parameter may have changed with iOS8.

Is anyone else seeing this on iOS8? Did something change in iOS8 that I am not aware of? Is this an iOS bug?

[UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference for openURL](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:)

Comment: I am seeing this too

Comment: A related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240631/openurl-in-appdelegate-conversion-error-nsstring-string-swift-ios8 has an answer that states the sourceApplication is optional, but never saw this in iOS7.

Comment: I filed a bug report... https://bugreport.apple.com you might want to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! I too just filed a bug report with an simple project demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I was just reviewing the related question you mentioned... I see the answer does state it is optional in swift and it appears it needs to be optional otherwise I get the crash just like the original poster of that related question. However, I cannot find where in the swift documentation or the UIApplicationDeletegate Cmd-Click "swift generated header" code that is is optional. I do not have enough reputation points to ask that question in the comments of that answer.

Comment: The current version of the swift documentation does not show it as optional. I added a comment to that answer.

Comment: My bug report was closed as a Duplicate of 17917841 which is Open.

Comment: I am getting this error on 8.1

Answer (score 0):

## iOS 9+

The value is nil unless the apps were created by your team

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/openurloptionskey/1623128-sourceapplication#discussion) say:

> The value of this key is an NSString object containing the bundle ID of the app that made the request. If the request originated from another app belonging to your team, UIKit sets the value of this key to the ID of that app. If the team identifier of the originating app is different than the team identifier of the current app, the value of the key is nil.

If you "Jump to Definition" for sourceApplication, you see

```
extension UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey {

    @available(iOS 9.0, *)
    public static let sourceApplication: UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey
```

(At this time, I doubt there is any available documentation to explain the reported behavior in iOS 8.)